# Use tinymce with popup plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I try to load tinymce scripts for my site:

```
<script src="/Content/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but during the process I receive `TypeError: tinymce is null` from `tiny_mce_popup.js`

Is there a problem with tinymce?
I use tinymce 3.5.6

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I should not put these two files together. `tiny_mce_popup.js` should be used only in the document which should be a popup.